# Any proper way of getting installed GPU model

Tags: c++, windows, gpu

-Windows

Is there any other ways of getting GPU Model, expect WMIC and direct9. Currently using directx10 and can't seem to find any proper way to retrieve the installed GPU.

Comment: So far i found EnumDisplayDevices, however, this only states the actual model instead of the full name. Example Radeon RX

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/ns-wingdi-display_devicea?redirectedfrom=MSDN Maybe might help

Comment: Tried that already, can't seem to get the full model name for the installed GPU